# how do I get the name of application launched by subprocess in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am launching the text editor but for different users the default text editor could be different, so how do I get the name of which text editor is being used just to handle if an error occur switch to different text editor ?

Comment: In order to get better answers be more specific: how do you launch the editors? Which operating system are you on? Can you provide example code?

Comment: Impossible in full generality. What you are discussing is platform specific and you asked a question without specifying a platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're working in a Linux/POSIX environment you could read the `EDITOR` environment variable using the `os.environ` map.

Comment: That's a rather amazing deduction